# How to get last inserted in database in Medoo framework

Tags: medoo

> Please help me am not able to get the last inserted Id in medoo

Below is my code:

> ```
>  <?php
>         header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
>         header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
>         header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
>         require 'vendor/autoload.php';
>         $app = new\Slim\Slim();
>         $app->container->singleton('db',function () use ($app) {
>             return new medoo([
>             'database_type' =>'pgsql',
>             'database_name' =>'emergency',
>             'server'=>'localhost',
>             'username' =>'postgres',
>             'password' => 'root',
>             'charset' => 'utf8',
>             'option' =>[
>                 PDO::ATTR_CASE=>PDO::CASE_NATURAL
>             ]
>             ]);
>         });
> $app->db->post('/getinfo',function()
> {
> $body = $app->request->post();
>  $app->db->insert("emergencymessages", [
>
>             "message" =>$body["msg"],
>             "createdby"=>$createdby
>             ]); 
> });
> ```
>
> Now i want to get last inserted id of emergencymessages table how can
>   i get it??

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs (http://medoo.in/api/insert) the `insert` function returns the last insert id.

```
$last_insert_id = $app->db->insert("emergencymessages", [
              "message" =>$body["msg"],
              "createdby"=>$createdby
            ]);
```

EDIT:

What you can try is to call `lastInsertId();` directly on medoo's `pdo` object:

```
$last_insert_id = $app->db->pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: but this gives me nothing :(

Comment: firstly i did this but i did not get id

Comment: Hmm this is strange. Does the data get correctly inserted?

Comment: And what's the output of `var_dump($app->db->error())`?